# Use bootstrap popover in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap popover which works outside of an angular `ng-repeat`.

```
<a href="#" class="tt1" data-trigger="hover" data-html="true" data-selector="" data-original-title="first tooltip" data-content="fldsfkjsdöflsj dlfödjs">Hover over me</a>
```

As soon as I use it inside an ng-repeat it stops working.
I initialize the popover in the angular controller constructor.

```
$('.tt1').popover();
```

Comment: should never use any DOM manipulation code in controllers

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should create a popover directive.

```
angular.module('yourModule').directive('popover', function() {
   return function(scope, elem) {
      elem.popover();
   }
});
```

Then you use it on the element:

```
<a href="#" class="tt1" popover data-trigger="hover" data-html="true" data-selector="" data-original-title="first tooltip" data-content="fldsfkjsdöflsj dlfödjs">Hover over me</a>
```